# Office Mac 2011 : How to create a new Word document and save it with applescript?

Tags: ms-word, applescript

I am trying to write simple applescript for Word on Office 2011 without success.
I found this link but syntax is different for Office 2011 and google is not my friend on this task...
http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.23/23.01/2301applescript/index.html

What I want : create a new doc, write the date and save the new doc in my home folder

Here is what I tried :

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
activate
make new document
set theDate to current date
set text of active document to theDate as text
save as active document file name "/Users/user/toto.doc"
end tell
```

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

This works on my Mountain Lion + MS Word 2011 :

```
set outputPath to (path to home folder as string) & "toto.doc"

tell application "Microsoft Word"
    activate
    make new document
    set theDate to ((current date) as string)
    tell active document
        set theRange to create range start 0 end 0
        set content of theRange to theDate
    end tell
    set activeDoc to active document
    save as activeDoc file name outputPath
end tell
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: unfortunately, with your script on SnowLeo, I get an error related to Save as :

*error "Erreur dans Microsoft Word : active document ne comprend pas le message save as." number -1708 from active document*

Comment: Thanks Tchap ! Ok I get it : the path format has to be like "Users:myuser:TestFolder:"

Comment: Yes! But you'd be better off using the programmatic `path to home folder` expression instead of a hard-coded one, always a better practice

Comment: ok I believed it was something to replace ^^. it's so strange to have a programmation language that sounds like real sentences.